# Obtener datos laravel con relación entre tablas

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo los siguiente modelos de datos:

```
    class Cliente extends Model
    {
         public function sector()
         {
               return $this->belongsTo(Sector::class,'sectoresId');
         }
    }
    class Sector extends Model
    {
         public function sectorLanguage()
         {
               return $this->hasMany(SectorLanguage::class,'sectoresId');
         }

         public function cliente()
         {
              return $this->hasMany(ClienteLanguage::class,'sectoresId');
         }
    }
    class SectorLanguage extends Model
    {
         public function sector()
         {
            return $this->belongsTo(Sector::class,'sectoresId');
         }

         public function idioma()
         {
            return $this->belongsTo(Idioma::class,'idiomasId');
         }
   }
```

Lo que quiero es recuperar todos los clientes activos y el nombre del sector al que pertenece, si hago algo así

```
   $cliente = Cliente::where('active','1');
```

Cuando recorro $cliente no puedo entrar al atributo

```
   foreach($cliente as $cli) {
      $cli->sector->sectorLanguage->nombre;
   }
```

Solo me funciona si lo obtengo por id

```
  $cliente = Cliente::find(1);
  echo $cliente->sector->sectorLanguage->nombre;
```

Como puedo obtener lo que necesito sin recurrir a hacer yo la SQL con Query Builder.

Comment: por que no haces un join de todos esos modelos

Comment: Se puede hacer con joins, pero quiero saber si existe una solución sin hacer los joins.

Comment: se puede hace un join pero no es el mas optimo para la consultas

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te está faltando el get luego del where. De la siguiente manera:

```
    $cliente = Cliente::where('active','1')->get();
```

Espero te sea de utilidad!

Comment: Eso no soluciona mi error ni en el controlador ni luego en el template

Answer (score 0):

Creo que cuando defines la funcion para recuperar la relacion te falta el getResults, por ejemplo:

```
public function sector()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Sector::class,'sectoresId')->getResults();
}
```

O simplemente usa el getResults cuando intentes recuperar la relacion:

```
$cli->sector->getResults();
```

Ten en cuenta el tipo de relacion, porque si getResults devuelve mas de un resultado no puedes acceder al atributo sectorLanguage. Tendrias que usar otro foreach para recorrer la coleccion. Seria el caso de sectorLanguage, ya que es un hasMany y esto devolvera una lista.

```
foreach($cli->sector->getResults()->sectorLanguage->getResults() as $sectorLan) {
    $sectorLan->nombre;
}
```

Ademas cuando recuperes los clientes tienes que usar el get

```
$cliente = Cliente::where('active','1')->get();
```

Espero que esto solucione tu problema

Comment: `getResults()` no debería ser necesario en este contexto, Laravel puede manejar las relaciones como propiedades sin ese método.

Answer (score 0):

Vale, he encontrado el 'problema' que no es tal, como en el modelo he puesto:

```
class Sector extends Model
{
     public function sectorLanguage()
     {
           return $this->hasMany(SectorLanguage::class,'sectoresId');
     }

     public function cliente()
     {
          return $this->hasMany(ClienteLanguage::class,'sectoresId');
     }
}
```

Es decir un sector tiene varios sectorLanguage por lo que no podia acceder a la propiedad

```
$cli->sector->sectorLanguage->nombre
```

porque no existe, existe el

```
$cli->sector->sectorLanguage[0]->nombre
```

Siempre usando lo que ha dicho el compañero Emiliano Torres

```
$cliente = Cliente::where('active','1')->get();
```

La siguiente pregunta que me surge es ¿Como seleccionar el sector en el idioma que yo quiero para todos mis clientes?

Comment: Si tienes otro problema, deberías entonces crear una nueva pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

le puedo ayudar si quiere mas informacion visite este link [laravel Eloquent: Relationships error a imprimir los datos en la vista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/148105/laravel-eloquent-relationships-error-a-imprimir-los-datos-en-la-vista?noredirect=1#comment277223_148105)

```
    $Cliente = Cliente::with('sector_pk','sectorLanguage_pk')
    ->where('active', '=', 1)
    ->get();
```

**en el modelo Cliente tiene que lococa el siguiente funcion**

```
    funcion public function sector_pk()
    {
        //archivo de modelo y el campo foreign_key Solicitude_estado 
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Sector','sectoresId');   
    } 
    funcion public function sectorLanguage_pk()
    {
        //archivo de modelo y el campo foreign_key Solicitude_estado 
        return $this->hasMany('App\SectorLanguage','sectoresId');   
    } 


    **
```

y en la vista coloque  var_dump($Cliente); me va a imprimir un array con 
        los datos relacionales por ejemplo:

**

```
<?= var_dump($Cliente);?>

 {
    "id":1,
    "sectoresId":2,
    "id_estado":2,
    "created_at":"2018-03-08 21:53:12",
    "updated_at":"2018-03-09 02:53:12",
    "usuarios_id":1,"
    sector_pk":
           {
           "id":2,
           "descripcion":"en procesor",
           "created_at":"2017-11-08 23:26:09",
           "updated_at":"2017-10-29 07:19:04"
           }
    }
```