# laravel Eloquent: Relationships error a imprimir los datos en la vista

Tags: laravel-5, arraylist, eloquent

estoy realizando una consulta con elounque y estoy usando el with() aqui esta el codigo, la idea es que el campo id_estado es una llave forania y y esa llave atraer mas datos, realizo la consulta el poblemas es cuando lo imprimer me sale error

```
$Solicitude = SolicitudeModel::with('id_estado')->get();
return view('Solicitude.index', [ 
"id_tipo" => $id_tipo,
"id_estado" => $id_estado,
"usuarios_id" => $usuarios_id, 
'listmysql' => $Solicitude
]);
```

en el modelo esta asi:

```
<?php
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class SolicitudeModel extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'solicitudes';
        protected $fillable = [
        ];
        public function id_estado()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Solicitude_estado','id_estado');   
        }
    }
```

y en la vista me imprimer

los datos de la consulta

```
  {
"id":1,
"descripcion":"contando de cable de energiaw",
"id_tipo":2,
"id_estado":{"id":2,"descripcion":"en procesor","created_at":"2017-11-08 23:26:09","updated_at":"2017-10-29 07:19:04"},
"created_at":"2018-03-08 21:53:12",
"updated_at":"2018-03-09 02:53:12",
"usuarios_id":1}

{
"id":2,
"descripcion":"arbol de control 2",
"id_tipo":2,
"id_estado":{"id":1,"descripcion":"pendiente","created_at":"2017-11-08 23:26:09","updated_at":"2017-10-29 07:19:04"},
"created_at":"2018-03-06 10:30:00",
"updated_at":"2017-11-09 05:34:10",
"usuarios_id":1}
```

y en la vista para imprimir los datos lo tengo de la siguiente manera

```
  @foreach($listmysql as $lists)
                                    <?= $lists ?>
            <td class="col1">{{ $lists->id }}</td>
            <td class="col1">{{ $lists->descripcion }}</td>
            <td class="col1">{{ $lists->id_tipo }}</td>
            //linea donde sale el error 
            <td class="col1">{{$lists->id_estado->id }}</td>
   @endforeach
```

Comment: no entiendo, si en la vista te imprime los valores como lo muestras en tu texto anterior, donde esta el error?

Comment: este es el tipo de error, la cuenstion es que ya tengo varias horas intentando resolviendo  `Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ArbolMapsv2\resources\views\Solicitude\index.blade.php)` en la vista esta es la linea        ` <td class="col1"><?php echo e($lists->id_estado->id); ?></td>`

Comment: por que seguramente al valor que intentas tratar es un array entonces este operador -> esta de mas

Comment: pudieras tratar así $lists->id_estado['id']

Comment: ¿Esa relación está entregando un json o un array o qué?

Comment: pudieras tratar así  ´ $lists->id_estado['id']´ ya lo intenter pero sale vacio, sin error

Comment: ¿qué muestra el dump o dd de `$lists->id_estado`?

Comment: Estás seguro que que todas las solicitudes tienen asociado un estado? en la plantilla podrías verificar eso también haciendo algo así @if( count($lists->id_estado) ) {{ $lists->id }} @endif

Comment: todas las solicitudes estasn asociadas a un estado? ya que por ejemplo ahora nos comentas que no devuelve un error pero que no te muestra tampoco un error podrías darnos mas información

Comment: aqui le dejor un link con pantallazo https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eu3pkas01e1dznj/AAByWnGYaN8BpqqVdxks6UDHa?dl=0

Comment: Estoy casi segura de que hay alguna solicitud que no tiene asociado un estado.  
Hacé esto     
 @foreach($listmysql as $lists) dump($lists->id) <br> dump($lists->id_estado)@endforeach  
  Y fijate cual es el ultimo id que te imprime antes de que tire el error, ese `id` es el que no tiene asociado un estado o tiene mal asociado un estado quizá. 
Por cierto, sería genial que veas de seguir las convenciones así te va a simplificar bastante solucionar estas cosas. Es solo un consejo, está en vos aceptarlo o no

Comment: ya encontre la solucion

Answer (score -1):

ya pude resolver el problemas con el with por lo cual le voy a publicar mi respuesta , la conclusión cuando declaramos un With() tiene que declararlo con otro nombre que no sea el mismo campo de forey key

en el controlador realizamos la consulta

```
    $Solicitude = SolicitudeModel::with('id_estado_pk')->get();
    return view('Solicitude.index', 
      [ 
        "id_tipo" => $id_tipo,
        "id_estado" => $id_estado,
        "usuarios_id" => $usuarios_id, 
        'listmysql' => $Solicitude
      ]);
```

en el modelo SolicitudeModel colocamos la siguiente linea

```
 funcion public function id_estado_pk()
    {
        //archivo de modelo y el campo foreign_key 
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Solicitude_estado','id_estado');   
    }
```

y en la vista nos devuelve la siguiente consulta

```
{
"id":1,
"descripcion":"contando de cable de energiaw",
"id_tipo":2,
"id_estado":2,
"created_at":"2018-03-08 21:53:12",
"updated_at":"2018-03-09 02:53:12",
"usuarios_id":1,"
id_estado_pk":
       {
       "id":2,
       "descripcion":"en procesor",
       "created_at":"2017-11-08 23:26:09",
       "updated_at":"2017-10-29 07:19:04"
       }
}
{
"id":2,
"descripcion":"arbol de control 2",
"id_tipo":2,
"id_estado":1,
"created_at":"2018-03-06 10:30:00",
"updated_at":"2017-11-09 05:34:10",
"usuarios_id":1,
"id_estado_pk":
         {
         "id":1,
         "descripcion":"pendiente",
         "created_at":"2017-11-08 23:26:09",
         "updated_at":"2017-10-29 07:19:04"
         }
} 
{
"id":7,
"descripcion":"tinoeesddeeewwww",
"id_tipo":2,
"id_estado":2,
"created_at":"2018-03-06 10:30:00",
"updated_at":"2017-11-09 05:34:10",
"usuarios_id":1,
"id_estado_pk":
         {
        "id":2,
        "descripcion":"en procesor",
        "created_at":"2017-11-08 23:26:09",
        "updated_at":"2017-10-29 07:19:04"
         }
}
```

y en la vista seria asi

```
@foreach($listmysql as $lists)
                    <td class="col1">{{ $lists->descripcion }}</td>
                    <td class="col1">{{ $lists->id_tipo }}</td>
                    <td class="col1">
                    {{$lists->id_estado }}

                    {{$lists->id_estado_pk->descripcion }}          
                    </td>


                    <td class="col1">{{ $lists->created_at }}</td>
                    <td class="col1">{{ $lists->updated_at }}</td>
                    <td class="col1">{{ $lists->usuarios_id }}</td>
            @endforeach
```